# Serialize form data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I've inherited some PHP code, never having worked with it before, and I'm stuck. I've tried to use `echo` like I would `console.log()` in JS, but I'm hardly getting into the script.

I'm trying to post 3 input values and a select option to PHP code, and email that information off to someone. Fairly simple I would assume.

### HTML

```
        <form method="post" class="contact-form" id="register-form">
            <fieldset> 
                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 input-text" id="firstName" required>

                <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 input-text" id="lastName" required>

                <input type="text" name="location_preference" placeholder="Location Preference" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 input-text" id="locationPreference" required>

                    <select name="internType" style="width: 100%; display: block; color: #000;" id="internType" required>
                        <option selected="" value="default">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="inside">Inside</option>
                        <option value="outside">Outside</option>
                        <option value="open">Open</option>
                    </select>
                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success submitinformation pull-right" id="submit"> Submit</button>
                <button name="reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-success submitinformation pull-right" id="reset"> Reset</button>

            </fieldset> 
        </form>
```

Pretty basic..

### JavaScript

```
    var PATH =  'processor.php';
    var APP = 'wse01010';

    $("#register-form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

        var errors = 0;
        var inputs = $('input:text, #internType'); 

            $(inputs).map(function(){
                if( !$(this).val() || $(this).val() == "default") {
                  $(this).addClass('warning'); //Add a warning class for inputs if Empty
                  errors++;
            } else if ($(this).val()) {
                  $(this).removeClass('warning');
            }   
            });

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    //console.log($(this)[0]);
    //var formData = new FormData( $(this)[0] );
    //console.log(formData);

            if(errors < 1) {
            // If no errors, send POST
                $.ajax({
                    url: PATH + '?i=' + APP,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,   
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                           alert('Request failed. Please try again.');
                        }

                });
            }

    });
```

This alerts `Success` every time.

### PHP

```
$firstName = $_POST['first_name'];

        if( !isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        var_dump($_POST);  // This gives me an empty array: array(0) { }
                $outcomeArr = array(
                                        'outcome'=>'failure',
                                        'message'=>'Step 1 failed.'
                                    );
            echo json_encode( $outcomeArr );
            exit();
        }

        unset( $_POST['submit'] );

        $postVar = print_r($_POST,true);
        //Other code omitted
```

Here's how the data is being passed.

[image]

I'm not sure how to get my Form Data into the correct format (if that's the issue), or why PHP isn't recognizing my `POST`. I'm also not sure of any other checks I should be doing to validate the `POST`.

This is the JavaScript that ended up working for me

```
var form_processor = {

settings : {
    'outcome' : -1,
    'status' : 0, // 0 == correct, 1 == errors detected
    'error_msg' : '',
    'path' : 'processor.php',
    'app' : 'wse01010'
},


sendData : function(formData){
    var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                        url: self.settings.path + '?i=' + self.settings.app ,  
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,   
                        async: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            toastr.success('Your request went through!', "Success")
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                           toastr.error("Something went wrong. Please try again.", "Error!")
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
            });
},

bindForm : function(){
    var self = this;
    $('.contact-form').submit(function(e){
        self.settings.formObj = $(e.target);

        e.preventDefault();

        var errors = 0;
        var inputs = $('input:text, #internType'); 

        $(inputs).map(function(){
                if( !$(this).val() || $(this).val() == "default") {
                  $(this).addClass('warning'); //Add a warning class for inputs if Empty
                  errors++;
            } else if ($(this).val()) {
                  $(this).removeClass('warning');
            }   
        });

        if( errors > 0 ) {  
            self.settings.status = 0;
            self.settings.error_msg = '';   
            toastr.error("Please fill in all of the fields.", "Error!")             
            return false
        } else {
            formData = new FormData( $(this)[0] );
            self.sendData(formData);
        }
    });
},
init : function(){
    this.bindForm();
}
}
form_processor.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP, you start off with this:

```
echo "1";
```

When using AJAX, an `echo` is the same as a `return`, so this is where your function stops. Remove all unnecessary `echo`'s or your function will simply not continue.

Furthermore, you are using spaces in your HTML name attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="first name"> <!-- Incorrect -->
```

Use underscores instead or you will not be able to retrieve the value properly:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name"> <!-- Correct -->
```

Afterwards, `$firstName = $_POST["first_name"];` is the correct way to retrieve your values in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did what you advised, and changed the first check to `$_POST['first_name']` and it's still hitting that block and saying it's not set.. Any other ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you get as output? Can you update your question and add your current PHP code?

Comment: `array(0) { } {"outcome":"failure","message":"Step 1 failed."}`.. That first `json_encode` response. Edited my question.

Comment: @Invent-Animate Well, *is* the first_name input field filled in while you are trying this? If it is, check your console and see if it's properly filled in in `formData`.

Comment: Yes! That's what is so weird and frustrating. In my screen shot you can see at the bottom my form data.

Comment: Is there any other PHP code that is not posted in the question but may be relevant?

Comment: Yes -- but it isn't even being reached.. and I am baffled as to why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73769/discussion-between-dark-ashelin-and-invent-animate).

Comment: @Invent-Animate Really? That doesn't make much sense since it's on the same website. I meant any PHP code before `$firstName = $_POST['first_name'];`?

Comment: I agree. My work is dumb. And no - sorry. I thought you meant inside the block. Everything I have that is preventing the script from running is shown

Comment: And just to be sure, you don't have this code in multiple places right? `$outcomeArr = array('outcome'=>'failure',  'message'=>'Step 1 failed.');`

Comment: PS: Try adding `69.59.197.29 chat.stackoverflow.com` to your hosts file and see if it's unblocked then xD

Comment: No, that error code is all that's there..Could I be using an older version of PHP.. or is my code expecting and object and I'm passing it JSON? I honestly not sure what's going on.

Comment: It should work like that, since I'm using the same code in one of my older projects and it works fine. Try `echo json_encode($_POST);` at the start of your PHP and see what that outputs?

Comment: I got nothing. Blank. No response at all

Comment: So there is something wrong with PHP receiving the data... You're sure that there is no code being executed before the PHP u posted? Maybe try `data: JSON.stringify(formData)` in your ajax call.

Comment: I got it working by using old (ugly) code.. but I still would love to know why this isn't working... If I figure anything out I will come back here. I'll update my question with the new javascript I used (that apparently PHP likes better)..

Comment: If you add those parameters `cache: false, contentType: false, processData: false` to your non-working javascript code, does it work?

Comment: No.. Still not working sadly. When I use that `FormData($(this)[0]);` code, it formats the `POST` differently, and I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm all out of idea's then. Hope you do eventually find out what caused it.

Comment: I hope so too. I really appreciate your time and effort. Thank you

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but now it works..I added a couple other things in the PHP file that I saw randomly to help error check, such as.. `if( isset( $_GET['i'] ) ) {

 if ( $_GET['i'] == 'wse01010' ) {`.. The serialize works (contentType json was incorrect for that answer below, btw).. I don't have an answer as to why it works now, but oh well. I'll give you the answer. Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to not use space in name so change that in firstname etc.

for serializing u need this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#register-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        var data = $("#register-form").serialize();
        $.getJSON("http://YOUR PHP FILE TO CATCH IT &",data)
                  });
});
```

on your php page use $_GET['firstname'] for example and add that to a variable.

Comment: This is a completely different method and is not necessary. His current way is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setting the content type of the form twice, and both times incorrectly:

- Drop `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the `<form>` tag. (This is for file uploads)
- Drop `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` from the jQuery `ajax()` call. (This is for JSON, which PHP does not understand natively)

The correct encoding is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the default value for both the `<form>` tag and the `ajax()` call.

Comment: Actually PHP does understand JSON natively and this is the correct/easiest way to use Ajax.

Comment: PHP will not parse a JSON POST body into `$_POST` unless you have something like [this PECL extension](http://www.pecl.php.net/package/json_post) installed. By default, jQuery sends POSTs as form-urlencoded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your method and received the same results.

Comment: Can you post the complete output from devtools? All the request/response header data?

Comment: Your code is still sending the request as `application/json; charset=utf-8`, did you remove the `contentType` line from your `ajax()` call? (You're essentially telling the server 'here's some JSON', and then not providing JSON, but `serialize()`d form data)

Comment: Also, note that your image doesn't have the Host: or Origin: lines blocked out, make sure that's OK

Comment: @mixedreturns I did remove the `contentType`, I just made that edit, sorry. Now, my `Form Data` in dev tools looks like: `first_name:hgh
last_name:hghgh
location_preference:gfhfghfgh
internType:outside`